# Custom ion-icon with SVG files made on Inkscape in Ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, svg, icons, inkscape

I'm having troubles displaying a custom `ion-icon` with a custom SVG made on Inkscape. My icon is received by the site (I can see it in the network tab in the Firefox developer tools) but its `div` container is empty.

I'm trying to display the icon in an `ion-item` like that:

```html
<ion-item button>
   <ion-icon name="custom-logo" slot="start"></ion-icon>
   <ion-label>Account</ion-label>
</ion-item>
```

I've configured the `angular.json` file, that's not the problem. I'm just applying this style-sheet rule to it:

```css
ion-icon {
    color: var(--ion-color-dark);
}
```

Here's the result of the HTML page I get on my browser (an empty `div.icon-inner`):

```html
<ion-icon _ngcontent-dxl-c134="" name="custom-logo" slot="start" ng-reflect-name="custom-logo" role="img" class="md hydrated" aria-label="custom logo">
   #shadow-root (open)
      <style>…</style>
      <div class="icon-inner"></div>
</ion-icon>
```

My custom SVG file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="6.35mm" height="6.3489mm" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 6.35 6.3489" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <title>Custom Logo</title>
 <defs>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1106">
   <stop stop-color="#fff" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="#646464" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1362-1" x1="63.286" x2="140.95" y1="540.13" y2="461.71" gradientTransform="translate(426.24 17.287)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
   <stop stop-color="#ff3e3b" offset="0"/>
   <stop stop-color="#2120ff" offset="1"/>
  </linearGradient>
  <clipPath id="clipPath1328-8">
   <circle cx="78.738" cy="583.32" r="40.831" fill="none" stroke-opacity="0"/>
  </clipPath>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1689" x1="54.051" x2="74.461" y1="544.29" y2="564.7" gradientTransform="translate(373.26 -207.84)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" xlink:href="#linearGradient1106"/>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1691" x1="54.051" x2="74.461" y1="544.29" y2="564.7" gradientTransform="translate(393.67 -207.84)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" xlink:href="#linearGradient1106"/>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1693" x1="54.051" x2="74.461" y1="544.29" y2="564.7" gradientTransform="translate(373.26 -187.43)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" xlink:href="#linearGradient1106"/>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1695" x1="54.051" x2="74.461" y1="544.29" y2="564.7" gradientTransform="translate(393.67 -187.43)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" xlink:href="#linearGradient1106"/>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1697" x1="54.051" x2="74.461" y1="544.29" y2="564.7" gradientTransform="translate(414.09 -207.84)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" xlink:href="#linearGradient1106"/>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1699" x1="54.051" x2="74.461" y1="544.29" y2="564.7" gradientTransform="translate(414.09 -187.43)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" xlink:href="#linearGradient1106"/>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1701" x1="54.051" x2="74.461" y1="544.29" y2="564.7" gradientTransform="translate(414.09 -228.25)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" xlink:href="#linearGradient1106"/>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1703" x1="54.051" x2="74.461" y1="544.29" y2="564.7" gradientTransform="translate(393.67 -228.25)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" xlink:href="#linearGradient1106"/>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1705" x1="54.051" x2="74.461" y1="544.29" y2="564.7" gradientTransform="translate(373.26 -228.25)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" xlink:href="#linearGradient1106"/>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1707" x1="54.051" x2="74.461" y1="544.29" y2="564.7" gradientTransform="translate(434.5 -228.25)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" xlink:href="#linearGradient1106"/>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1709" x1="54.051" x2="74.461" y1="544.29" y2="564.7" gradientTransform="translate(434.5 -207.84)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" xlink:href="#linearGradient1106"/>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1711" x1="54.051" x2="74.461" y1="544.29" y2="564.7" gradientTransform="translate(434.5 -187.43)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" xlink:href="#linearGradient1106"/>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1713" x1="54.051" x2="74.461" y1="544.29" y2="564.7" gradientTransform="translate(373.26 -167.02)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" xlink:href="#linearGradient1106"/>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1715" x1="54.051" x2="74.461" y1="544.29" y2="564.7" gradientTransform="translate(393.67 -167.02)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" xlink:href="#linearGradient1106"/>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1717" x1="54.051" x2="74.461" y1="544.29" y2="564.7" gradientTransform="translate(414.09 -167.02)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" xlink:href="#linearGradient1106"/>
  <linearGradient id="linearGradient1719" x1="54.051" x2="74.461" y1="544.29" y2="564.7" gradientTransform="translate(434.5 -167.02)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" xlink:href="#linearGradient1106"/>
 </defs>
 <metadata>
  <rdf:RDF>
   <cc:Work rdf:about="">
    <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
    <dc:type rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage"/>
    <dc:title>Custom Logo</dc:title>
   </cc:Work>
  </rdf:RDF>
 </metadata>
 <g transform="translate(-497.12 -466.94)">
  <g transform="matrix(.077312 0 0 .077312 458.69 430.84)">
   <g transform="matrix(1.0048 0 0 1.0048 459.12 -78.133)" clip-path="url(#clipPath1328-8)" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#646464" stroke-width=".01">
    <rect transform="rotate(45)" x="427.31" y="336.44" width="20.411" height="20.411" fill="url(#linearGradient1689)" opacity=".84828"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(45)" x="447.73" y="336.44" width="20.411" height="20.411" fill="url(#linearGradient1691)" opacity=".84828"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(45)" x="427.31" y="356.85" width="20.411" height="20.411" fill="url(#linearGradient1693)" opacity=".84828"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(45)" x="447.73" y="356.85" width="20.411" height="20.411" fill="url(#linearGradient1695)" opacity=".84828"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(45)" x="468.14" y="336.44" width="20.411" height="20.411" fill="url(#linearGradient1697)" opacity=".84828"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(45)" x="468.14" y="356.85" width="20.411" height="20.411" fill="url(#linearGradient1699)" opacity=".84828"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(45)" x="468.14" y="316.03" width="20.411" height="20.411" fill="url(#linearGradient1701)" opacity=".84828"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(45)" x="447.73" y="316.03" width="20.411" height="20.411" fill="url(#linearGradient1703)" opacity=".84828"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(45)" x="427.31" y="316.03" width="20.411" height="20.411" fill="url(#linearGradient1705)" opacity=".84828"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(45)" x="488.55" y="316.03" width="20.411" height="20.411" fill="url(#linearGradient1707)" opacity=".84828"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(45)" x="488.55" y="336.44" width="20.411" height="20.411" fill="url(#linearGradient1709)" opacity=".84828"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(45)" x="488.55" y="356.85" width="20.411" height="20.411" fill="url(#linearGradient1711)" opacity=".84828"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(45)" x="427.31" y="377.26" width="20.411" height="20.411" fill="url(#linearGradient1713)" opacity=".84828"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(45)" x="447.73" y="377.26" width="20.411" height="20.411" fill="url(#linearGradient1715)" opacity=".84828"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(45)" x="468.14" y="377.26" width="20.411" height="20.411" fill="url(#linearGradient1717)" opacity=".84828"/>
    <rect transform="rotate(45)" x="488.55" y="377.26" width="20.411" height="20.411" fill="url(#linearGradient1719)" opacity=".84828"/>
   </g>
   <circle cx="538.18" cy="508" r="41.026" fill="url(#linearGradient1362-1)" opacity=".84828" stroke-opacity="0"/>
   <g transform="translate(284.25 -120.42)" fill="none" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="9.265">
    <path d="m275.06 612.13c-6.2367 14.552-12.473 29.104-18.93 32.191-6.457 3.0868-13.134-5.2915-19.812-13.67" stroke="#212620" stroke-opacity=".39024"/>
    <path d="m271.55 611.85c-6.2367 14.552-12.473 29.104-18.93 32.191-6.457 3.0868-13.134-5.2915-19.812-13.67" stroke="#fff"/>
   </g>
  </g>
 </g>
 <script id="mesh_polyfill" type="text/javascript">!function(){const t="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg",e="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink",s="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",r=2;if(document.createElementNS(t,"meshgradient").x)return;const n=(t,e,s,r)=&gt;{let n=new x(.5*(e.x+s.x),.5*(e.y+s.y)),o=new x(.5*(t.x+e.x),.5*(t.y+e.y)),i=new x(.5*(s.x+r.x),.5*(s.y+r.y)),a=new x(.5*(n.x+o.x),.5*(n.y+o.y)),h=new x(.5*(n.x+i.x),.5*(n.y+i.y)),l=new x(.5*(a.x+h.x),.5*(a.y+h.y));return[[t,o,a,l],[l,h,i,r]]},o=t=&gt;{let e=t[0].distSquared(t[1]),s=t[2].distSquared(t[3]),r=.25*t[0].distSquared(t[2]),n=.25*t[1].distSquared(t[3]),o=e&gt;s?e:s,i=r&gt;n?r:n;return 18*(o&gt;i?o:i)},i=(t,e)=&gt;Math.sqrt(t.distSquared(e)),a=(t,e)=&gt;t.scale(2/3).add(e.scale(1/3)),h=t=&gt;{let e,s,r,n,o,i,a,h=new g;return t.match(/(\w+\(\s*[^)]+\))+/g).forEach(t=&gt;{let l=t.match(/[\w.-]+/g),d=l.shift();switch(d){case"translate":2===l.length?e=new g(1,0,0,1,l[0],l[1]):(console.error("mesh.js: translate does not have 2 arguments!"),e=new g(1,0,0,1,0,0)),h=h.append(e);break;case"scale":1===l.length?s=new g(l[0],0,0,l[0],0,0):2===l.length?s=new g(l[0],0,0,l[1],0,0):(console.error("mesh.js: scale does not have 1 or 2 arguments!"),s=new g(1,0,0,1,0,0)),h=h.append(s);break;case"rotate":if(3===l.length&amp;&amp;(e=new g(1,0,0,1,l[1],l[2]),h=h.append(e)),l[0]){r=l[0]*Math.PI/180;let t=Math.cos(r),e=Math.sin(r);Math.abs(t)&lt;1e-16&amp;&amp;(t=0),Math.abs(e)&lt;1e-16&amp;&amp;(e=0),a=new g(t,e,-e,t,0,0),h=h.append(a)}else console.error("math.js: No argument to rotate transform!");3===l.length&amp;&amp;(e=new g(1,0,0,1,-l[1],-l[2]),h=h.append(e));break;case"skewX":l[0]?(r=l[0]*Math.PI/180,n=Math.tan(r),o=new g(1,0,n,1,0,0),h=h.append(o)):console.error("math.js: No argument to skewX transform!");break;case"skewY":l[0]?(r=l[0]*Math.PI/180,n=Math.tan(r),i=new g(1,n,0,1,0,0),h=h.append(i)):console.error("math.js: No argument to skewY transform!");break;case"matrix":6===l.length?h=h.append(new g(...l)):console.error("math.js: Incorrect number of arguments for matrix!");break;default:console.error("mesh.js: Unhandled transform type: "+d)}}),h},l=t=&gt;{let e=[],s=t.split(/[ ,]+/);for(let t=0,r=s.length-1;t&lt;r;t+=2)e.push(new x(parseFloat(s[t]),parseFloat(s[t+1])));return e},d=(t,e)=&gt;{for(let s in e)t.setAttribute(s,e[s])},c=(t,e,s,r,n)=&gt;{let o,i,a=[0,0,0,0];for(let h=0;h&lt;3;++h)e[h]&lt;t[h]&amp;&amp;e[h]&lt;s[h]||t[h]&lt;e[h]&amp;&amp;s[h]&lt;e[h]?a[h]=0:(a[h]=.5*((e[h]-t[h])/r+(s[h]-e[h])/n),o=Math.abs(3*(e[h]-t[h])/r),i=Math.abs(3*(s[h]-e[h])/n),a[h]&gt;o?a[h]=o:a[h]&gt;i&amp;&amp;(a[h]=i));return a},u=[[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[-3,3,0,0,-2,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[2,-2,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,-3,3,0,0,-2,-1,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,-2,0,0,1,1,0,0],[-3,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,-2,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,-3,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,-2,0,-1,0],[9,-9,-9,9,6,3,-6,-3,6,-6,3,-3,4,2,2,1],[-6,6,6,-6,-3,-3,3,3,-4,4,-2,2,-2,-2,-1,-1],[2,0,-2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,2,0,-2,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0],[-6,6,6,-6,-4,-2,4,2,-3,3,-3,3,-2,-1,-2,-1],[4,-4,-4,4,2,2,-2,-2,2,-2,2,-2,1,1,1,1]],f=t=&gt;{let e=[];for(let s=0;s&lt;16;++s){e[s]=0;for(let r=0;r&lt;16;++r)e[s]+=u[s][r]*t[r]}return e},p=(t,e,s)=&gt;{const r=e*e,n=s*s,o=e*e*e,i=s*s*s;return t[0]+t[1]*e+t[2]*r+t[3]*o+t[4]*s+t[5]*s*e+t[6]*s*r+t[7]*s*o+t[8]*n+t[9]*n*e+t[10]*n*r+t[11]*n*o+t[12]*i+t[13]*i*e+t[14]*i*r+t[15]*i*o},y=t=&gt;{let e=[],s=[],r=[];for(let s=0;s&lt;4;++s)e[s]=[],e[s][0]=n(t[0][s],t[1][s],t[2][s],t[3][s]),e[s][1]=[],e[s][1].push(...n(...e[s][0][0])),e[s][1].push(...n(...e[s][0][1])),e[s][2]=[],e[s][2].push(...n(...e[s][1][0])),e[s][2].push(...n(...e[s][1][1])),e[s][2].push(...n(...e[s][1][2])),e[s][2].push(...n(...e[s][1][3]));for(let t=0;t&lt;8;++t){s[t]=[];for(let r=0;r&lt;4;++r)s[t][r]=[],s[t][r][0]=n(e[0][2][t][r],e[1][2][t][r],e[2][2][t][r],e[3][2][t][r]),s[t][r][1]=[],s[t][r][1].push(...n(...s[t][r][0][0])),s[t][r][1].push(...n(...s[t][r][0][1])),s[t][r][2]=[],s[t][r][2].push(...n(...s[t][r][1][0])),s[t][r][2].push(...n(...s[t][r][1][1])),s[t][r][2].push(...n(...s[t][r][1][2])),s[t][r][2].push(...n(...s[t][r][1][3]))}for(let t=0;t&lt;8;++t){r[t]=[];for(let e=0;e&lt;8;++e)r[t][e]=[],r[t][e][0]=s[t][0][2][e],r[t][e][1]=s[t][1][2][e],r[t][e][2]=s[t][2][2][e],r[t][e][3]=s[t][3][2][e]}return r};class x{constructor(t,e){this.x=t||0,this.y=e||0}toString(){return`(x=${this.x}, y=${this.y})`}clone(){return new x(this.x,this.y)}add(t){return new x(this.x+t.x,this.y+t.y)}scale(t){return void 0===t.x?new x(this.x*t,this.y*t):new x(this.x*t.x,this.y*t.y)}distSquared(t){let e=this.x-t.x,s=this.y-t.y;return e*e+s*s}transform(t){let e=this.x*t.a+this.y*t.c+t.e,s=this.x*t.b+this.y*t.d+t.f;return new x(e,s)}}class g{constructor(t,e,s,r,n,o){void 0===t?(this.a=1,this.b=0,this.c=0,this.d=1,this.e=0,this.f=0):(this.a=t,this.b=e,this.c=s,this.d=r,this.e=n,this.f=o)}toString(){return`affine: ${this.a} ${this.c} ${this.e} \n       ${this.b} ${this.d} ${this.f}`}append(t){t instanceof g||console.error("mesh.js: argument to Affine.append is not affine!");let e=this.a*t.a+this.c*t.b,s=this.b*t.a+this.d*t.b,r=this.a*t.c+this.c*t.d,n=this.b*t.c+this.d*t.d,o=this.a*t.e+this.c*t.f+this.e,i=this.b*t.e+this.d*t.f+this.f;return new g(e,s,r,n,o,i)}}class w{constructor(t,e){this.nodes=t,this.colors=e}paintCurve(t,e){if(o(this.nodes)&gt;r){const s=n(...this.nodes);let r=[[],[]],o=[[],[]];for(let t=0;t&lt;4;++t)r[0][t]=this.colors[0][t],r[1][t]=(this.colors[0][t]+this.colors[1][t])/2,o[0][t]=r[1][t],o[1][t]=this.colors[1][t];let i=new w(s[0],r),a=new w(s[1],o);i.paintCurve(t,e),a.paintCurve(t,e)}else{let s=Math.round(this.nodes[0].x);if(s&gt;=0&amp;&amp;s&lt;e){let r=4*(~~this.nodes[0].y*e+s);t[r]=Math.round(this.colors[0][0]),t[r+1]=Math.round(this.colors[0][1]),t[r+2]=Math.round(this.colors[0][2]),t[r+3]=Math.round(this.colors[0][3])}}}}class m{constructor(t,e){this.nodes=t,this.colors=e}split(){let t=[[],[],[],[]],e=[[],[],[],[]],s=[[[],[]],[[],[]]],r=[[[],[]],[[],[]]];for(let s=0;s&lt;4;++s){const r=n(this.nodes[0][s],this.nodes[1][s],this.nodes[2][s],this.nodes[3][s]);t[0][s]=r[0][0],t[1][s]=r[0][1],t[2][s]=r[0][2],t[3][s]=r[0][3],e[0][s]=r[1][0],e[1][s]=r[1][1],e[2][s]=r[1][2],e[3][s]=r[1][3]}for(let t=0;t&lt;4;++t)s[0][0][t]=this.colors[0][0][t],s[0][1][t]=this.colors[0][1][t],s[1][0][t]=(this.colors[0][0][t]+this.colors[1][0][t])/2,s[1][1][t]=(this.colors[0][1][t]+this.colors[1][1][t])/2,r[0][0][t]=s[1][0][t],r[0][1][t]=s[1][1][t],r[1][0][t]=this.colors[1][0][t],r[1][1][t]=this.colors[1][1][t];return[new m(t,s),new m(e,r)]}paint(t,e){let s,n=!1;for(let t=0;t&lt;4;++t)if((s=o([this.nodes[0][t],this.nodes[1][t],this.nodes[2][t],this.nodes[3][t]]))&gt;r){n=!0;break}if(n){let s=this.split();s[0].paint(t,e),s[1].paint(t,e)}else{new w([...this.nodes[0]],[...this.colors[0]]).paintCurve(t,e)}}}class b{constructor(t){this.readMesh(t),this.type=t.getAttribute("type")||"bilinear"}readMesh(t){let e=[[]],s=[[]],r=Number(t.getAttribute("x")),n=Number(t.getAttribute("y"));e[0][0]=new x(r,n);let o=t.children;for(let t=0,r=o.length;t&lt;r;++t){e[3*t+1]=[],e[3*t+2]=[],e[3*t+3]=[],s[t+1]=[];let r=o[t].children;for(let n=0,o=r.length;n&lt;o;++n){let o=r[n].children;for(let r=0,i=o.length;r&lt;i;++r){let i=r;0!==t&amp;&amp;++i;let h,d=o[r].getAttribute("path"),c="l";null!=d&amp;&amp;(c=(h=d.match(/\s*([lLcC])\s*(.*)/))[1]);let u=l(h[2]);switch(c){case"l":0===i?(e[3*t][3*n+3]=u[0].add(e[3*t][3*n]),e[3*t][3*n+1]=a(e[3*t][3*n],e[3*t][3*n+3]),e[3*t][3*n+2]=a(e[3*t][3*n+3],e[3*t][3*n])):1===i?(e[3*t+3][3*n+3]=u[0].add(e[3*t][3*n+3]),e[3*t+1][3*n+3]=a(e[3*t][3*n+3],e[3*t+3][3*n+3]),e[3*t+2][3*n+3]=a(e[3*t+3][3*n+3],e[3*t][3*n+3])):2===i?(0===n&amp;&amp;(e[3*t+3][3*n+0]=u[0].add(e[3*t+3][3*n+3])),e[3*t+3][3*n+1]=a(e[3*t+3][3*n],e[3*t+3][3*n+3]),e[3*t+3][3*n+2]=a(e[3*t+3][3*n+3],e[3*t+3][3*n])):(e[3*t+1][3*n]=a(e[3*t][3*n],e[3*t+3][3*n]),e[3*t+2][3*n]=a(e[3*t+3][3*n],e[3*t][3*n]));break;case"L":0===i?(e[3*t][3*n+3]=u[0],e[3*t][3*n+1]=a(e[3*t][3*n],e[3*t][3*n+3]),e[3*t][3*n+2]=a(e[3*t][3*n+3],e[3*t][3*n])):1===i?(e[3*t+3][3*n+3]=u[0],e[3*t+1][3*n+3]=a(e[3*t][3*n+3],e[3*t+3][3*n+3]),e[3*t+2][3*n+3]=a(e[3*t+3][3*n+3],e[3*t][3*n+3])):2===i?(0===n&amp;&amp;(e[3*t+3][3*n+0]=u[0]),e[3*t+3][3*n+1]=a(e[3*t+3][3*n],e[3*t+3][3*n+3]),e[3*t+3][3*n+2]=a(e[3*t+3][3*n+3],e[3*t+3][3*n])):(e[3*t+1][3*n]=a(e[3*t][3*n],e[3*t+3][3*n]),e[3*t+2][3*n]=a(e[3*t+3][3*n],e[3*t][3*n]));break;case"c":0===i?(e[3*t][3*n+1]=u[0].add(e[3*t][3*n]),e[3*t][3*n+2]=u[1].add(e[3*t][3*n]),e[3*t][3*n+3]=u[2].add(e[3*t][3*n])):1===i?(e[3*t+1][3*n+3]=u[0].add(e[3*t][3*n+3]),e[3*t+2][3*n+3]=u[1].add(e[3*t][3*n+3]),e[3*t+3][3*n+3]=u[2].add(e[3*t][3*n+3])):2===i?(e[3*t+3][3*n+2]=u[0].add(e[3*t+3][3*n+3]),e[3*t+3][3*n+1]=u[1].add(e[3*t+3][3*n+3]),0===n&amp;&amp;(e[3*t+3][3*n+0]=u[2].add(e[3*t+3][3*n+3]))):(e[3*t+2][3*n]=u[0].add(e[3*t+3][3*n]),e[3*t+1][3*n]=u[1].add(e[3*t+3][3*n]));break;case"C":0===i?(e[3*t][3*n+1]=u[0],e[3*t][3*n+2]=u[1],e[3*t][3*n+3]=u[2]):1===i?(e[3*t+1][3*n+3]=u[0],e[3*t+2][3*n+3]=u[1],e[3*t+3][3*n+3]=u[2]):2===i?(e[3*t+3][3*n+2]=u[0],e[3*t+3][3*n+1]=u[1],0===n&amp;&amp;(e[3*t+3][3*n+0]=u[2])):(e[3*t+2][3*n]=u[0],e[3*t+1][3*n]=u[1]);break;default:console.error("mesh.js: "+c+" invalid path type.")}if(0===t&amp;&amp;0===n||r&gt;0){let e=window.getComputedStyle(o[r]).stopColor.match(/^rgb\s*\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\)$/i),a=window.getComputedStyle(o[r]).stopOpacity,h=255;a&amp;&amp;(h=Math.floor(255*a)),e&amp;&amp;(0===i?(s[t][n]=[],s[t][n][0]=Math.floor(e[1]),s[t][n][1]=Math.floor(e[2]),s[t][n][2]=Math.floor(e[3]),s[t][n][3]=h):1===i?(s[t][n+1]=[],s[t][n+1][0]=Math.floor(e[1]),s[t][n+1][1]=Math.floor(e[2]),s[t][n+1][2]=Math.floor(e[3]),s[t][n+1][3]=h):2===i?(s[t+1][n+1]=[],s[t+1][n+1][0]=Math.floor(e[1]),s[t+1][n+1][1]=Math.floor(e[2]),s[t+1][n+1][2]=Math.floor(e[3]),s[t+1][n+1][3]=h):3===i&amp;&amp;(s[t+1][n]=[],s[t+1][n][0]=Math.floor(e[1]),s[t+1][n][1]=Math.floor(e[2]),s[t+1][n][2]=Math.floor(e[3]),s[t+1][n][3]=h))}}e[3*t+1][3*n+1]=new x,e[3*t+1][3*n+2]=new x,e[3*t+2][3*n+1]=new x,e[3*t+2][3*n+2]=new x,e[3*t+1][3*n+1].x=(-4*e[3*t][3*n].x+6*(e[3*t][3*n+1].x+e[3*t+1][3*n].x)+-2*(e[3*t][3*n+3].x+e[3*t+3][3*n].x)+3*(e[3*t+3][3*n+1].x+e[3*t+1][3*n+3].x)+-1*e[3*t+3][3*n+3].x)/9,e[3*t+1][3*n+2].x=(-4*e[3*t][3*n+3].x+6*(e[3*t][3*n+2].x+e[3*t+1][3*n+3].x)+-2*(e[3*t][3*n].x+e[3*t+3][3*n+3].x)+3*(e[3*t+3][3*n+2].x+e[3*t+1][3*n].x)+-1*e[3*t+3][3*n].x)/9,e[3*t+2][3*n+1].x=(-4*e[3*t+3][3*n].x+6*(e[3*t+3][3*n+1].x+e[3*t+2][3*n].x)+-2*(e[3*t+3][3*n+3].x+e[3*t][3*n].x)+3*(e[3*t][3*n+1].x+e[3*t+2][3*n+3].x)+-1*e[3*t][3*n+3].x)/9,e[3*t+2][3*n+2].x=(-4*e[3*t+3][3*n+3].x+6*(e[3*t+3][3*n+2].x+e[3*t+2][3*n+3].x)+-2*(e[3*t+3][3*n].x+e[3*t][3*n+3].x)+3*(e[3*t][3*n+2].x+e[3*t+2][3*n].x)+-1*e[3*t][3*n].x)/9,e[3*t+1][3*n+1].y=(-4*e[3*t][3*n].y+6*(e[3*t][3*n+1].y+e[3*t+1][3*n].y)+-2*(e[3*t][3*n+3].y+e[3*t+3][3*n].y)+3*(e[3*t+3][3*n+1].y+e[3*t+1][3*n+3].y)+-1*e[3*t+3][3*n+3].y)/9,e[3*t+1][3*n+2].y=(-4*e[3*t][3*n+3].y+6*(e[3*t][3*n+2].y+e[3*t+1][3*n+3].y)+-2*(e[3*t][3*n].y+e[3*t+3][3*n+3].y)+3*(e[3*t+3][3*n+2].y+e[3*t+1][3*n].y)+-1*e[3*t+3][3*n].y)/9,e[3*t+2][3*n+1].y=(-4*e[3*t+3][3*n].y+6*(e[3*t+3][3*n+1].y+e[3*t+2][3*n].y)+-2*(e[3*t+3][3*n+3].y+e[3*t][3*n].y)+3*(e[3*t][3*n+1].y+e[3*t+2][3*n+3].y)+-1*e[3*t][3*n+3].y)/9,e[3*t+2][3*n+2].y=(-4*e[3*t+3][3*n+3].y+6*(e[3*t+3][3*n+2].y+e[3*t+2][3*n+3].y)+-2*(e[3*t+3][3*n].y+e[3*t][3*n+3].y)+3*(e[3*t][3*n+2].y+e[3*t+2][3*n].y)+-1*e[3*t][3*n].y)/9}}this.nodes=e,this.colors=s}paintMesh(t,e){let s=(this.nodes.length-1)/3,r=(this.nodes[0].length-1)/3;if("bilinear"===this.type||s&lt;2||r&lt;2){let n;for(let o=0;o&lt;s;++o)for(let s=0;s&lt;r;++s){let r=[];for(let t=3*o,e=3*o+4;t&lt;e;++t)r.push(this.nodes[t].slice(3*s,3*s+4));let i=[];i.push(this.colors[o].slice(s,s+2)),i.push(this.colors[o+1].slice(s,s+2)),(n=new m(r,i)).paint(t,e)}}else{let n,o,a,h,l,d,u;const x=s,g=r;s++,r++;let w=new Array(s);for(let t=0;t&lt;s;++t){w[t]=new Array(r);for(let e=0;e&lt;r;++e)w[t][e]=[],w[t][e][0]=this.nodes[3*t][3*e],w[t][e][1]=this.colors[t][e]}for(let t=0;t&lt;s;++t)for(let e=0;e&lt;r;++e)0!==t&amp;&amp;t!==x&amp;&amp;(n=i(w[t-1][e][0],w[t][e][0]),o=i(w[t+1][e][0],w[t][e][0]),w[t][e][2]=c(w[t-1][e][1],w[t][e][1],w[t+1][e][1],n,o)),0!==e&amp;&amp;e!==g&amp;&amp;(n=i(w[t][e-1][0],w[t][e][0]),o=i(w[t][e+1][0],w[t][e][0]),w[t][e][3]=c(w[t][e-1][1],w[t][e][1],w[t][e+1][1],n,o));for(let t=0;t&lt;r;++t){w[0][t][2]=[],w[x][t][2]=[];for(let e=0;e&lt;4;++e)n=i(w[1][t][0],w[0][t][0]),o=i(w[x][t][0],w[x-1][t][0]),w[0][t][2][e]=n&gt;0?2*(w[1][t][1][e]-w[0][t][1][e])/n-w[1][t][2][e]:0,w[x][t][2][e]=o&gt;0?2*(w[x][t][1][e]-w[x-1][t][1][e])/o-w[x-1][t][2][e]:0}for(let t=0;t&lt;s;++t){w[t][0][3]=[],w[t][g][3]=[];for(let e=0;e&lt;4;++e)n=i(w[t][1][0],w[t][0][0]),o=i(w[t][g][0],w[t][g-1][0]),w[t][0][3][e]=n&gt;0?2*(w[t][1][1][e]-w[t][0][1][e])/n-w[t][1][3][e]:0,w[t][g][3][e]=o&gt;0?2*(w[t][g][1][e]-w[t][g-1][1][e])/o-w[t][g-1][3][e]:0}for(let s=0;s&lt;x;++s)for(let r=0;r&lt;g;++r){let n=i(w[s][r][0],w[s+1][r][0]),o=i(w[s][r+1][0],w[s+1][r+1][0]),c=i(w[s][r][0],w[s][r+1][0]),x=i(w[s+1][r][0],w[s+1][r+1][0]),g=[[],[],[],[]];for(let t=0;t&lt;4;++t){(d=[])[0]=w[s][r][1][t],d[1]=w[s+1][r][1][t],d[2]=w[s][r+1][1][t],d[3]=w[s+1][r+1][1][t],d[4]=w[s][r][2][t]*n,d[5]=w[s+1][r][2][t]*n,d[6]=w[s][r+1][2][t]*o,d[7]=w[s+1][r+1][2][t]*o,d[8]=w[s][r][3][t]*c,d[9]=w[s+1][r][3][t]*x,d[10]=w[s][r+1][3][t]*c,d[11]=w[s+1][r+1][3][t]*x,d[12]=0,d[13]=0,d[14]=0,d[15]=0,u=f(d);for(let e=0;e&lt;9;++e){g[t][e]=[];for(let s=0;s&lt;9;++s)g[t][e][s]=p(u,e/8,s/8),g[t][e][s]&gt;255?g[t][e][s]=255:g[t][e][s]&lt;0&amp;&amp;(g[t][e][s]=0)}}h=[];for(let t=3*s,e=3*s+4;t&lt;e;++t)h.push(this.nodes[t].slice(3*r,3*r+4));l=y(h);for(let s=0;s&lt;8;++s)for(let r=0;r&lt;8;++r)(a=new m(l[s][r],[[[g[0][s][r],g[1][s][r],g[2][s][r],g[3][s][r]],[g[0][s][r+1],g[1][s][r+1],g[2][s][r+1],g[3][s][r+1]]],[[g[0][s+1][r],g[1][s+1][r],g[2][s+1][r],g[3][s+1][r]],[g[0][s+1][r+1],g[1][s+1][r+1],g[2][s+1][r+1],g[3][s+1][r+1]]]])).paint(t,e)}}}transform(t){if(t instanceof x)for(let e=0,s=this.nodes.length;e&lt;s;++e)for(let s=0,r=this.nodes[0].length;s&lt;r;++s)this.nodes[e][s]=this.nodes[e][s].add(t);else if(t instanceof g)for(let e=0,s=this.nodes.length;e&lt;s;++e)for(let s=0,r=this.nodes[0].length;s&lt;r;++s)this.nodes[e][s]=this.nodes[e][s].transform(t)}scale(t){for(let e=0,s=this.nodes.length;e&lt;s;++e)for(let s=0,r=this.nodes[0].length;s&lt;r;++s)this.nodes[e][s]=this.nodes[e][s].scale(t)}}document.querySelectorAll("rect,circle,ellipse,path,text").forEach((r,n)=&gt;{let o=r.getAttribute("id");o||(o="patchjs_shape"+n,r.setAttribute("id",o));const i=r.style.fill.match(/^url\(\s*"?\s*#([^\s"]+)"?\s*\)/),a=r.style.stroke.match(/^url\(\s*"?\s*#([^\s"]+)"?\s*\)/);if(i&amp;&amp;i[1]){const a=document.getElementById(i[1]);if(a&amp;&amp;"meshgradient"===a.nodeName){const i=r.getBBox();let l=document.createElementNS(s,"canvas");d(l,{width:i.width,height:i.height});const c=l.getContext("2d");let u=c.createImageData(i.width,i.height);const f=new b(a);"objectBoundingBox"===a.getAttribute("gradientUnits")&amp;&amp;f.scale(new x(i.width,i.height));const p=a.getAttribute("gradientTransform");null!=p&amp;&amp;f.transform(h(p)),"userSpaceOnUse"===a.getAttribute("gradientUnits")&amp;&amp;f.transform(new x(-i.x,-i.y)),f.paintMesh(u.data,l.width),c.putImageData(u,0,0);const y=document.createElementNS(t,"image");d(y,{width:i.width,height:i.height,x:i.x,y:i.y});let g=l.toDataURL();y.setAttributeNS(e,"xlink:href",g),r.parentNode.insertBefore(y,r),r.style.fill="none";const w=document.createElementNS(t,"use");w.setAttributeNS(e,"xlink:href","#"+o);const m="patchjs_clip"+n,M=document.createElementNS(t,"clipPath");M.setAttribute("id",m),M.appendChild(w),r.parentElement.insertBefore(M,r),y.setAttribute("clip-path","url(#"+m+")"),u=null,l=null,g=null}}if(a&amp;&amp;a[1]){const o=document.getElementById(a[1]);if(o&amp;&amp;"meshgradient"===o.nodeName){const i=parseFloat(r.style.strokeWidth.slice(0,-2))*(parseFloat(r.style.strokeMiterlimit)||parseFloat(r.getAttribute("stroke-miterlimit"))||1),a=r.getBBox(),l=Math.trunc(a.width+i),c=Math.trunc(a.height+i),u=Math.trunc(a.x-i/2),f=Math.trunc(a.y-i/2);let p=document.createElementNS(s,"canvas");d(p,{width:l,height:c});const y=p.getContext("2d");let g=y.createImageData(l,c);const w=new b(o);"objectBoundingBox"===o.getAttribute("gradientUnits")&amp;&amp;w.scale(new x(l,c));const m=o.getAttribute("gradientTransform");null!=m&amp;&amp;w.transform(h(m)),"userSpaceOnUse"===o.getAttribute("gradientUnits")&amp;&amp;w.transform(new x(-u,-f)),w.paintMesh(g.data,p.width),y.putImageData(g,0,0);const M=document.createElementNS(t,"image");d(M,{width:l,height:c,x:0,y:0});let S=p.toDataURL();M.setAttributeNS(e,"xlink:href",S);const k="pattern_clip"+n,A=document.createElementNS(t,"pattern");d(A,{id:k,patternUnits:"userSpaceOnUse",width:l,height:c,x:u,y:f}),A.appendChild(M),o.parentNode.appendChild(A),r.style.stroke="url(#"+k+")",g=null,p=null,S=null}}})}();</script>
</svg>
```

I've seen [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56653936/how-do-i-make-my-custom-svg-icons-display-correctly-inkscape-ionic-4) but it concerned Ionic 4, plus I've made the suggested solutions and it didn't work. I've exported the SVG in Inkscape as optimized SVG (but I tried other SVG format and it didn't work better). My issue is probably because of the SVG but what do I have to change to make it work?

Comment: Have you try using a path? Like: `<ion-icon src="/path/to/icon.svg"><ion-icon>`

Comment: Yes with the same result, that's really not the problem.

Comment: Seems like there's something wrong with the script tag. I removed it, tested without it and i can see your purple checkmark icon.

Comment: OK that's really weird, I was sure to have tested it already, but apparently not. Anyway, it worked, thanks. Although, I don't know why it was causing problems, the script was generated by Inkscape, I have no idea what for.